# owox data connector API failed

Tags: database, api, google-bigquery, connector

Earlier my big query owox data connector was working fine but now getting "owox data connector API failed"
and not able to retrieve my query too, can anyone help, how to retrieve the query.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some API error . It’s solved now